# Next page links with pagination

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pagination, ejs

I've implemented pagination into my controller file

```
exports.products = async (req, res) => {
  const pagination = req.query.pagination ? parseInt(req.query.pagination) : 5;
  const page = req.query.page ? parseInt(req.query.page) : 1;
  const prod = await Product.find({})
    .skip((page - 1) * pagination)
    .limit(pagination);
  res.render("products", {
    productsList: prod,
  });
};
```

The code above works, I can access 5 results per page by changing the URL from `/products?page=1` to `/products?page=2`  etc. but I haven't been able to find any information/tutorials that include how to implement the 'next page' links. What I mean is if I have 20 products and want to display 5 products per page, how can I make sure there won't be more than 4 'next page' links at the bottom. Do I have to calculate the number of pages inside my controller and pass that as a variable to my ejs and display the correct amount of links?

I'm just trying to make sure I take the correct approach to this with scaling in mind since I'm relatively new to this! Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is good you alreade return the product inside some object. you can use it to also return a count:

```js
  res.render("products", {
    productsList: prod,
    count: await Product.count({})
  });
```

devided by 'pagination' is the page count.

Comment: divided with Math.ceil() incase anyone else ever stumbles onto this question :)  thanks for the answer!